# Flame Ionization Detector versus Mass Spectrometer

Tags: analytical-chemistry

Why is chromatographic separation more important with a flame ionization detector than with a mass spectrometer?

Answer (score 2):

FID requires separation as it is not specific and cannot distinguish 2 non separated compounds.

MS is specific and can determine the particular compound even qualitatively.

For complex matrices, it is always good to have saparation even for MS, as MS spectrum of mixture would be confusing.